# Disable automatic telephone number linking does not work in Android

Tags: c#, android, html, ios

```
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Above code disabled mobile format number in IOS but not Android devices.

**I need to clarify. It works in Android's webbrowser but not the native email client.**

Any idea how to fix it?

Cheers

Comment: this is the tag which does the trick. Hope you've placed it inside the head tag. Only thing missing here is the closing of meta tag <meta ... />, you are missing the slash(/). May b it does the trick for you.

Comment: Yes it is inside head

Comment: did you check the closing tag thing as well?

Comment: Yes. sadly does not work as well :(

Comment: Do you know if this works for Android devices before?

Comment: Yup, I've the same line in my code and works like a charm.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34823/discussion-between-shank-and-overule)

Comment: we tested in Samsung galaxy tab 2. It works in web browser but not the native email client.
Can you double Check yours?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using.

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Number here</a>
```